# How to handle duplicate question, where it's on different Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

I came across [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1181876/ping-my-vm-with-ubuntu) on Super User and noticed there's [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177809/how-to-ping-ubuntu-guest-on-virtualbox) (with what I believe is also the correct answer) on Stack Overflow.

Is there a way to mark or link nicely the question in Super User to the one on Stack Overflow?

I guess that actually they both should be on the same site, so maybe one of them should be migrated?

Comment: Thanks! Haven't found that question when searching for it.